# Swift SpriteKit turning sprite to certain angle

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In Swift SpriteKit I have the "angle" of a sprite stored in an integer. It starts at zero and adds or subtracts 45 whenever the user rotates left or right (0-360), how would I create an SKAction to rotate the sprite to the stored angle? (in the case that the angle gets shifted unintentionally)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS generally uses radians to describe angles. You'll need to convert your angle in degrees to radians before you can create the action.

```
let radAngle = CGFloat(angle) * .pi / 180
let rotationAction = SKAction.rotateToAngle(radAngle, duration: 0.5)
node.runAction(rotationAction)
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS 11.x Swift 4.2 a translation of [Clever Error](https://stackoverflow.com/users/385017/clever-error) answer

```
let radAngle = CGFloat(10) * .pi / 180
let rotationAction = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: radAngle, duration: 0.5)
floor.run(rotationAction)
```